# How do I undelete my answers?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, vote-to-undelete

I have many deleted answers. How can I *undelete* them?

I've seen other answers that say you can undelete them, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Go to the answer, click 'undelete'.

Answer (score 20):

With the **undelete** link:

[image: picture with link]

You may need other users to vote for undeletion if the community deleted it. The link would still be there though.

Note that you *definitely* can't do this if a moderator deleted the post; you can tell this by the moderator diamond (♦) appearing after the name of the user in the part that says "deleted by" below the undelete link.  If a moderator deleted it; you will need to cast an "Other" flag asking for it to be undeleted. Make sure to include a justification for *why* you feel it should be undeleted.

---

If you need to **find** your recently-deleted answers, you can do so from your profile page. At the very bottom of your list of "answers", you'll see a link that says "deleted recent answers":

[image: deleted recent answers]

Click on that. It will take you to a page with a URL like:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/<YourUserID>
```

However, as the name suggests, only your *recently* deleted answers will be listed here. You won't be able to find old answers this way. (You'd need to have a bookmark or some other saved URL pointing you directly to them.)

Comment: This doesn't help if you can't remember what question the answer was from.

Comment: @dps  
stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/{userId} may be helpful with that. Otherwise I think mods can see the full list

Comment: @BradletDotNet this does help.  It's only for recently deleted (not all deleted), but better than nothing.

Comment: I'm a moderator and don't see this option. I also don't see how to cast a undelete vote. This is the post I'm trying to undelete. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3582293/1231

Comment: @DonnyV. You aren't a diamond mod and have <20k rep. You need 20k to undelete other user's posts. That post was deleted by an actual moderator so the community can't help. You need to just cast a flag on it as explained in the post.

Comment: "You may need other users to vote for undeletion if the community deleted it." - I don't believe this is the case if you want to undelete one of your own answers. Having recently observed this behaviour... the answer went through the review queue and 4 users voted for deletion and the answer was deleted. However, the OP then simply "undeleted" their answer! The answer in question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66802406/369434 (which has since been deleted again... by a mod).

Comment: Can I undelete my own ans which was deleted by me and edit and repist the same?

Comment: I can't see my a while-ago deleted answer, which was the answer on the off-topic question. I have even created a meta question on that later.. but I can't seem to find that post as well.. I have spent quite a time back then, on writing that answer.. now, I'd like to copy that text for my student's reference. Could anyone, please be so kind and post the link for me to that deleted answer? it was about Spring vs. Spring Boot vs. Spring MVC.. I've got <10k rep, so I can't see it.. and nor do I know where to ask for that link.