# User repeatedly deletes and re-posts the same question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, new-users

How should I deal with a new user who repeatedly deletes a question just to ask it again exactly the same way (including typos)? I tried to explain to the user why this is impolite and even raised a moderator flag in this, but this is getting silly...

One of the first versions already had an answer.

---

The user accidentally deleted the question. I recommended looking at [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275752/how-do-i-undelete-my-answers), but I realize that it is just for *answers*. How can the user undelete their question?

Comment: You're doing the right thing, flag it for moderator attention and provide these details and they will investigate and take action if the user is repeatedly doing it. Being on meta will more than likely have the desired impact in this case.

Comment: That said, if they keep it up, the question ban will kick in rather quickly, and then they can't ask any more.

Comment: I don't think the user understood how to find them, either, honestly. The post you linked them to mentions answers, and has a link to recently deleted answers (for the OP of the meta question) but doesn't explain how to find them. I left a comment for the OP explaining that part. Basically, the undelete process is the same for both (find the post, click "undelete") but finding them is ever-so-slightly different and wasn't mentioned on that post.

Comment: How many times did the user re-post?

Comment: @faintsignal I know of at least three: The first one I commented on, the second one I additionally flagged, the third one is the present one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You handled the situation pretty well and did what you should have. Indicating to the user that this is unacceptable behaviour is always a good start, and flagging a moderator is also a good idea when a user is repeatedly deleting/reposting questions. Though if this is only the first repost, comment first in case it was a simple mistake such as with this particular user.

As for undeleting, the OP needs to go to the "Questions" tab in their profile, scroll to the bottom, and click the "Recently Deleted Questions" link. In the case of answers, it's the same process, but in the "Answers" tab instead.

Once they find the post they wish to undelete, they will need to click the "Undelete" link at the bottom of the post. If the post was deleted by the community, they will not be able to single-handedly undelete the post. If a diamond mod deleted the post, the OP will have to flag "Other" and explain why they think the post should be undeleted.

When they have the original post undeleted, it's best to delete the duplicate post, or at the very least close it as a duplicate of the original.